# How to disable all cells except the selected one

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

How can I disable interaction with all `cells` except the selected one, and then enable the interaction after cell is selected again?

I tried like this inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
if cell.isExpanded
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
            self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = false
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
    }
```

But this will disable the entire `tableView` including the currently selected `cell`.

Comment: Did you read table view delegate methods?

Comment: Which one you suggest to use to get it done?

Comment: The one that disables cell selection.

Comment: Well I don't want to cancel selection effect, I want to disable interaction with other cells as long as one of them is selected which means some boolean value is true for that cell

Answer (score 3):

As of first your `tableView` need to select cell, after that one of the cell is selected you want other cell not to select except that selected cell, for that you can create one instance property of type `NSIndexPath` and use this to store inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, and compare its value inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like this way.

```
var selectedIndexPath: NSIndexPath?
```

**cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomCell
    if (self.selectedIndexpath != nil) {
        if self.selectedIndexpath == indexPath {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
        }
        else {
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false
        }
    }
    else {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    return cell
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if self.selectedIndexpath != indexPath {
        self.selectedIndexpath = indexPath
    }
    else {
        self.selectedIndexpath = nil
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:** I have set the cell `userInteractionEnabled` to true again if you select your expanded cell.

Comment: Tried, this is not working in my case, since this early data reload messed up my cells

Comment: Something without reloading tableView should work in my opinion

Comment: @DCDC I don't think so without reloading it is possible, because you want others cells to become disable.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

to findout the selected cell and store the indexPath selected in a variable and reload the tableview.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

disable all the cells except the one selected by checking the stored indexPath.

Hope this helps .